# Presupposition in logic

Tags: logic, philosophy

Let S be a presupposition for Q. For example:

1. S: I used to smoke
2. Q: I quit smoking

**As far as I know, Q has a truth value if and only if S is true.** However, my understanding of the concept of presupposition contradicts this, so I feel that I'm wrong—but where and how?

**I feel that if S is false, Q has the truth value *False*.** Because for quitting smoking I have to had been smoking before. Starting is the necessary condition for quitting. And If I didn't satisfy this condition, then I just logically can't quit smoking. Therefore I just didn't quit. That is, Q is false, which means that it does have a truth value.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  As a matter of English usage, if someone said "I quit  some activity or other" I would definitely interpret that as saying "I used to do that particular activity but I stopped."  so, in this particular context, if you never smoke, you can never quit smoking.  But this is a matter of English usage, not math.

Comment: I agree to that , @ryang , It is the last Paragraph of my Answer , comparing Atomic Statement with Compound Statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Posting this Answer , at the risk of getting Downvoted , to aid the new OP , who should include more Context/Details to the Question Post , Eg Where was the Question from , What OP thinks is the wrong/right way , Why OP wants to look into this.

**Background :**

Essentially , this is a matter of Semantics , Linguistics , Philosophy & Natural Languages , not generally covered in regular Mathematical Logic texts.

Linguistics & Philosophy texts cover this in Detail.
Eg :
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presupposition/ lists 150+ Articles.

In terms of Mathematical Logic , there are some treatments in some theories by some authors , though it is not covered in texts like "Logic and Structure - Dirk Van Dalen" & "Logic for Mathematicians - Yuri I. Manin"

**OP Query :**

**(1)** The main Objection (out of many other Objections) is that this will not satisfy PEM the Principle of Excluded Middle , which says that Either "a Proposition $X$ is true" or "it is not true & $\lnot X$ is true" : there is no other alternative & Both can not be true.

In OP Case :
PEM says that : if we take "I quit smoking" is true , then "I did not quit smoking" is not true , while if we take "I quit smoking" is not true , then "I did not quit smoking" is true.

But the OP Way of thinking makes Both true , which Contradicts PEM.

$S$ : I used to smoke
$Q_1$ : I quit smoking
$Q_2$ : I did not quit smoking

PEM : If we take $Q_1$ is not true , $\lnot Q_1$ must be true.
PEM : If we take $Q_2$ is true , $\lnot Q_1$ must be not true.
OP Way : Both $Q_1$ & $\lnot Q_1$ are true , Both $Q_2$ & $\lnot Q_2$ are not true.

**Conclusion : It is not whether $Q$ & $Q_1$ & $Q_2$ can have truth value , it is whether that truth value is Consistent.**

**(2)** One other Issue to look into is that the truth value of $Q$ (which is not valid by itself) can always make $S$ true , whether that is the Intention or not.
Eg : "Did the Army stop murdering Civilians ?" , "Did the gangster continue to beat the neighbours ?" , "Did the Minister know that the assistant was involved in Corruption ?"
The Questions can be made into Propositions "The Army stopped murdering Civilians" & "The gangster continued to beat the neighbours" & "The Minister knew that the assistant was involved in Corruption"
No matter whether these are true or not , that will automatically make the Presumptions true :
"The Army was earlier murdering Civilians" & "The gangster was earlier beating the neighbours" & "The assistant was involved in Corruption"

Hence , Mathematical Logic will not generally treat these as **Atomic Propositions** , in general. There are some authors who treat these as **Compound Propositions** , though that is rare.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. I used to smoke - S
> 2. I quit smoking - Q
>
> But I feel that, even if S is false, Q still can have truth value.

Since you want the *loaded statement* "I quit smoking" to formally have a truth value regardless of the truth value of `S`, I suggest the clearer and actually consistent alternative interpretation

1. S: I used to smoke
2. Q: I still smoke

so that "I quit smoking" is formalised as `S ∧ ¬Q` instead.